# Codefolding in Jupiter notebook text editor

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

Is there a way to get code folding in Jupiter notebook text editor (not the ipynb editor)

e.g., you can use the text editor to edit raw python files:
[image: example image]

and I'd like to be able to collapse functions and such (just like in the ipynb editor with the code folding extension)